# What would have happened if the USA never dropped atomic bomb in Hiroshima and Nagasaki?

Tags: warfare, alternate-history, history, japan

If the USA never dropped the bombs on Japan, how different would have japan looked today?

Would it look like Taiwan or would it look like Europe?

What would have been Japan's technological innovation? How would have been Japan's electronics industry?

Comment: I think you're presenting a false dichotomy with the "Taiwan vs Europe" question - there's no particular reason it should be either.  Question would be better without that line.

Comment: Even without three questions this is rather broad.

Comment: Maybe the USA would use Project X-ray, where they release bats carrying incinerator bombs to set fire to houses. Might be an interesting avenue to explore.

Comment: I should mention the project was cancelled for a reason, hence why this is only a comment

Comment: Shrug. The surrender of Japan would have been delayed a month, maybe two. Giving Russia a bit more influence in the area, they were making *great* strides against Japan at the end of the war.. Rather ask how the COld War would have evolved, without a demonstrated willingness by the US to use nuclear weapons on civilian targets. The soviet paranoia towards the west would have been much less, and the memories of the aid from the west during WW2 would have been more relevant. Maybe an era of better east-west cooperation?

Answer (score 8):

Japan as we know it and its broader cultural impact wouldn't exist today. Plan B if the atomic bomb wasn't dropped was [Operation Downfall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_Downfall): an amphibious invasion of Japan. This invasion would have been mostly U.S. personnel with limited support from the U.K. The U.S. military *dreaded* the idea of invading Japan. The battles for Okinawa and Iwo Jima showed that the Japanese were willing to fight to the last man, as well as use inhumane tactics such as faking surrender before blowing themselves up and deliberately targeting medics. Or wound GI's, let the screams draw a medic or stretcher party, and them ambush them all. And, of course, the ever famous kamikaze tactics. Not only that, but even in the event that the Americans won, [Japanese civilians (including women, children, and the elderly as well as Korean slaves and "comfort women" would kill themselves in mass suicides](https://www.atomicheritage.org/history/japanese-mass-suicides) because the Japanese government had convinced them that the Americans were inhuman monsters and if they took the island the Americans would murder, rape, torture, and cannibalize them ([which](https://www.independent.co.uk/news/world/japanese-troops-ate-flesh-enemies-and-civilians-1539816.html) [is rather](https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/india/japanese-ate-indian-pows-used-them-as-live-targets-in-wwii/articleshow/40017577.cms) [ironic](https://archives.frontpagemag.com/point/unbroken-japan-still-deep-denial-over-cannibalism-daniel-greenfield)), and that it was better to die than be taken alive.

> "As the mayhem unfolded, they found all sorts of ways to kill…Men bashed their wives and parents bashed their children, young people killed the elderly and the strong killed the weak. What they felt in common was the belief that they were doing this out of love and compassion"
> --Ota Masahide, historian and survivor of the Okinawan mass suicides

I have heard stories of Okinawan women jumping off cliffs to try and escape American soldiers who were trying to convince them that they were safe. Some of the suicides may have been forced by Japanese soldiers. It is estimated about [50% of Okinawa's civilian population died in mass suicides.](https://www.reuters.com/article/us-japan-history-okinawa/historians-battle-over-okinawa-ww2-mass-suicides-idUST29175620070406)

This is what the American government was expecting, but on steroids because the Japanese would be extra fanatical because they were defending their homes and livelihoods instead of far-flung colonies, and had the local population to draw on for defense. Projected American casualties were anywhere from several hundred thousand to several *million*, possibly up to six million if one extrapolates the casualty rate at Okinawa to the main islands of Japan (which would have bled the U.S. white). That's not even getting into projected casualty rates for the Japanese. The projected casualty rate was so bad that the U.S. made 500,000 Purple Hearts in anticipation of the casualties for Operation Downfall, and the U.S. still hasn't run out of them out of all the casualties through the Korean War, Vietnam, Afghanistan, and both Iraq Wars. It would have possibly been one of the bloodiest military engagements in American military history (if not world history), period.

That's right, the idea of invading Japan by land was considered to be such a potential horror show that the atomic bombs were considered the more moral option.

But you don't have to take the U.S. government's word for it, after World War II [a Japanese military officer was asked what he thought would have happened if the bombs hadn't dropped](https://www.theatlantic.com/magazine/archive/1946/12/if-the-atomic-bomb-had-not-been-used/376238/). He agreed that the U.S. would probably have tried to invade Japan by sea, and even gave suggestions as to where they might have done it. He thought that ultimately the invading Americans would have won, but the battle would have been brutal, the Japanese would have not surrendered and kept on fighting until every Japanese man (and possibly woman) was killed. Japan at this time was filled with fanatics due to imperial propaganda, with most Japanese people believing they were *winning* the war right up until the bombs dropped.

If you want to know how fanatical the Japanese military was, note that the Japanese military [tried to perform a coup d'etat to overthrow the Japanese Emperor to prevent him from surrendering to the U.S.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ky%C5%ABj%C5%8D_incident) That is: **they wanted to overthrow the guy most Japanese people saw as a living demigod because they wanted to keep fighting a losing war** ***after*** **the bombs dropped**.

Ironically Emperor Hirohito's motivations for ordering some of the atrocities were to make the American government think Japan was so fanatical they would negotiate a peace treaty rather than continue war. It kind of backfired.

More broadly, if Operation Downfall went as planned, the Japanese people had a very real risk of going *extinct*, simply because they would have fought to the last instead of surrendering when all hope was lost, whether it was out of a fanatical ideology or the fact that they didn't want their homes invaded. The U.S. would be invading the home turf of a county with a highly fanatical ideology who would fight to the death because they were cornered, [which was a worst-case scenario from a military strategy point of view](https://suntzusaid.com/book/7/36/). But there weren't a lot of other options to stop Japanese aggression. The bombs were dropped because it was thought they would end up *saving* the lives of all the American personnel that would have been lost in Operation Downfall, as well as the numerous, numerous Japanese military and civilian casualties.

Lets say Operation Downfall went as planned but the Japanese people were not driven extinct. Nevertheless, the collective trauma and mass casualties (at least half of the Japanese population, if not in excess of 90%) would have left Japan scarred for centuries to come, and the population would likely have not recovered by the present day. It would be a historical horror story on par with the Holocaust, albeit one that would have been a bit more morally gray because a lot of the tragedy would have been due to the fact that Japan wouldn't have just surrendered to spare the lives of their citizens and many of the civilian deaths would have been mass suicides due to propaganda.

On top of that, it is likely that the USSR would have turned its attention to Japan and bitten off a chunk of it, likely taken territory at least all the way up to Hokkaido. It's not clear how much Russia could actually administrate the territory, but Japan would probably be missing its northernmost island and due to its severely reduced position politically would have no way to get it back. The USSR would have likely demanded a chunk of Japan anyway for getting involved similar to what happened with Korea.

Japan would also never recover and would not have become the tech and cultural powerhouse it is today. Japan was able to recover from the war like a phoenix because the American government poured huge amounts of money into Japan and helped the Japanese people rebuild their government. This wouldn't have happened if Operation Downfall had gone on, because the atrocities of the Japanese theater and "dirty tactics" the Japanese would have used against U.S. soldiers would have left a bad taste in the Americans' mouths. The U.S. wouldn't have a lot of love for a country that loved employing suicide bombings, shooting medics, convincing women and children to kill themselves, and just about every other war crime under the rising sun, especially on a scale that may have killed millions of U.S. citizens. Japan would probably resent the U.S. for the invasion, and the bridges wouldn't be mended by the U.S. helping them rebuild. The two countries would have probably hated each other on the same scale that Korea and Japan do now.

Without reconstruction, the Japanese government never recovers economically and remains poor. Additionally, the sheer amount of Japanese hatred entering American culture from returning G.I.s and the widows of those who died in Japan mean that the U.S. becomes strongly anti-Japanese, so anime and manga never get a foothold here and weeb culture never becomes a thing. Godzilla and kaiju never become popular either. American never starts buying Japanese electronics or automobiles en masse, so Japan never becomes a tech giant as well. Japan likely ends up a permanent developing nation akin to a less dictatorial North Korea or Vietnam, and has a high chance of going communist, possibly to spite America if nothing else. Even if America needed a forward base in the region against communist, they would probably pour all their resources into (South) Korea rather than help Japan.

Comment: Excellent analysis and an interesting environment to write alternative history about.  This leads to some interesting follow up questions like which technologies and industries would have been lost along with the Japanese mind-share.  It is disturbing to think that we owe much of our modern technology to THE USE of the atomic bomb. This would be a beautiful method for introducing the idea of the positive results born of negative seeds which is a lesson which although distasteful to modern apologists, is worthy of exploration in tomorrow's fiction.  Thank you for this answer! +1

Comment: In addition to the above, if atomic bomb hadn't existed/been used, ironically it wouldn't likely have saved any lives even in the short term.  It is well documented that the US had been fiercely firebombing all Japanese cities, _except_ for the A-bomb target cities, for months already, causing immense firestorms that killed more people than the A-bombs did.  Nagasaki and Hiroshima would simply also have been leveled and had its population incinerated by intense firebombing before Operation Downfall.

Comment: @GrumpyYoungMan Yes. The A-bombs were supposed to be a flashy show of overwhelming force, and the American government desperately hoped the Japanese wouldn't call their bluff and notice they only had the two.

Comment: Three. The US had three atomic bombs. The third was not fully assembled, but was ready to go within days. Anyway, you mention the USSR possibly getting involved. If they had not, then China very likely would. China's attitude was really very extreme against Japan. Chances are that if Japan had not been re-built that China would have eyed some revenge actions.

Comment: Operation Downfall never had a chance in hell to go forward. The US navy would have starved Japan to death while the US Air force was burning their cities, until they surrendered. That's what actually happened, in fact, the atomic bombs being nothing but an anecdota at the footpage.

Answer (score 1):

Things would have turned out largely the same in the short term.

It's well documented that the Japanese government (aside from the military faction) was already in the process of trying to reach a negotiated settlement.  They had pinned their hopes on using the Soviet Union as an intermediary but, once it became clear that wasn't going to happen (the Soviet Union declared war on Japan on August 9th), they opened surrender talks with the United States directly.  Many argue that the Soviet Union's declaration of war alone would've been a sufficient push for the civilian faction and it's documented that the use of atomic weapons did not turn the military away from their desire to continue the war.

Had the atomic bombs not been available, Hiroshima and Nagasaki would have been part of the regular firebombing campaign in progress and been destroyed, along with their populations, anyway, minus the radioactive fallout.

Longer term, humanity being what it is, it seems likely that atomic bombs would have been used in some later conflict on a larger scale since the terrifying effects of radiation exposure hadn't entered the collective consciousness.

Answer (score 0):

This is a Worldbuilding forum.  I'm going to say that, because we failed to disqualify ourselves for the Intergalactic Federation by blowing up nuclear weapons on our own planet, friendly aliens landed and showed the nations of the world how to travel throughout the Universe.

Japan, Taiwan, and Europe all made abundant use of the immortality drug they brought us, though they were later disappointed to notice a slow irrevocable decline in fertility.  Fortunately the aliens were able to demonstrate methods of synthesizing humans free of genetic, physical and mental defects and vulnerabilities.  Humans returning from the other worlds, like those produced in labs, came back educated, cosmopolitan, physically and mentally enhanced.

In some of the Asian countries the upgraded humans preach variants of Tekno-Zen or neo-Shintoism which explain that as the Emperor had been the conduit between Earth and Heaven, now enhanced humans bring good news and good government to mankind.  Ordinary humans now have the opportunity to go and prove themselves of fundamental, permanent significance in galactic affairs by achieving technologically facilitated enlightenment (tekzazen).  This permits the perception of unutterable beauty and personal fulfillment in tasks like chopping wood and fetching water, when done as a status symbol for the Galactic Delegates who vie with one another to guide the future redevelopment of Earth and other planets.

Comment: @Rekesoft OP is clearly asking about an alternate history context, and this answer is off-topic and pure [alien space bats](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alien_space_bats). This answer is as off-topic as answering "magic" to somebody's hard sci-fi question.